# Get button-clicked color of theme

Tags: android, button, colors

Is there a way, to get the button-clicked colour based on the current theme? The best would be a xml @color that I can use.
I am planning to use this colour for my ImageButtons when pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an workaround. When you set this as background, the colour is changed automatically by the operating system according to the theme as if it was a button.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

If you want to use the attribute on pre API 11 devices you can use:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a specific color one time, you could hold the button down on your device and screenshot it.  Then open the image in MS Paint or something to grab the colors used.

Comment: Instead of such mmmm... actions, you can just use hierarchy viewer. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html
But I thought, that question is about getting color programmatically, isn't it?

Comment: Oh that's neat.  Yeah that's probably the better way to do it

Comment: Yes @krossovochkin, I want to get it programmatically. Either in xml or in java.